# @WebServlet annotation doesn't work with Tomcat 8

Tags: servlets, embedded-tomcat-8

I want to use the `@WebServlet` annotation in a Java EE webapp which runs on Tomcat 8.

I have read that I need to declare Servlet Version 3.1 in my `web.xml` and that my Servlet needs to extend `HttpServlet`. I did all that but still the `@WebServlet` doesn't work. I am getting a HTTP 404.

I also tried my configuration with `metadata-complete="false"` in my `web.xml`, but still no success.

Here is my web.xml and Servlet.

The complete sample code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/bennyn/heroku-test).

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
  version="3.1" 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/7924117/451634 -->
  <!-- Put "-1" to disable this feature -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>   

  <!-- CDI -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

**TestServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"*.serve"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    try (ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream()) {
      out.write("Hello World".getBytes());
      out.flush();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got it working. I had to extend the way I started my Tomcat 8.0.12 server.

Nevertheless, there are three main things that must be done:

1. `web-app version` in **web.xml** has to be at least 3.0 (*I used 3.1*)
2. `metadata-complete` in **web.xml** may not be true (`default is "false"`)
3. `classes` directories have to be added to the embedded Tomcat before start

Here is an example for the **web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
  version="3.1" 
  metadata-complete="false"  
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

This is how my Tomcat main class looks like (which supports now `@WebServlet` annotations):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String contextPath = "/";
  String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
  String baseDirectory = new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath();

  Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
  tomcat.setPort(8080);
  StandardContext context = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, baseDirectory);

  // Additions to make @WebServlet work
  String buildPath = "target/classes";
  String webAppMount = "/WEB-INF/classes";

  File additionalWebInfClasses = new File(buildPath);
  WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(context);
  resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, webAppMount, additionalWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), contextPath));
  context.setResources(resources);
  // End of additions

  tomcat.start();
  tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

Comment: This works sometimes, but other times leads to a [mysterious exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979989/).

Comment: See also [Embedded tomcat 7 servlet 3.0 annotations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507/embedded-tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-annotations-not-working)

Comment: If tomcat discovers a context.xml it will use it to override the one you are programmatically setting . Makes sure to set context.setOverride(true);  https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/ContextConfig.java#L585

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the lib you're using, like from javax to jakarta

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then change all javax.* imports to jakarta.*

Comment: This was the solution for me! I use Tomcat 10.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your `javax.servlet` version.

Make sure it's 3 or plus.

If not, change it to the latest one.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@WebServlet<"/name">` instead of `@WebServlet<"name">`
might work.

Answer (score -2):

How about @ServletComponentScan?

Example from http://www.baeldung.com/spring-servletcomponentscan

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAnnotatedApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAnnotatedApp.class, args);
    }
}
```