# Java EE - HTTP Error 404 - resource is not available - after hitting "Submit" button on page

Tags: java, forms, tomcat, jakarta-ee, http-status-code-404

My web program will allow a user to enter first name and last name and after the user press the submit button, it will print the first name and last name.

**I receive an HTTP error 404 after the user presses the "Submit" button.**

[image]

Error

[image]

This is my File structure

[image]

My codes

PrintFormContent.java

```
package form;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/PrintFormContent")
public class PrintFormContent extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PrintFormContent() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fname = request.getParameter("name");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");

         try{
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print("<p>First Name</p>" + fname);
                out.print("<p>Last Name</p>" + lname);

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Form Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="PrintFormContent" name="PrintFormContent" role="form"
        action="/testForm/form/PrintFormContent" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fname" class="col-md-2">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname"
                    placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="lname" class="col-md-2">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname"
                    placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>testForm</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrintFormContent</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>PrintFormContent</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/testForm/program/form/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

you declared your servlet to `PrintFormContent` but you send your request to `/testForm/form/PrintFormContent`. You need to change it in the form-declaration:

```
<form id="PrintFormContent" name="PrintFormContent" role="form"
    action="/PrintFormContent" method="POST">
```

btw. don't forget to change parameter name in the servlet to `fname`:

```
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
```

try to add this to web.xml, somehow your anotation seems not to work

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>PrintFormContent</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/PrintFormContent</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

check this, maybe you have the same problem: [webservlet-annotation-doesnt-work-with-tomcat-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089902/webservlet-annotation-doesnt-work-with-tomcat-8)

Comment: doesn't work. I even tried changing to @WebServlet("/testForm/form/PrintFormContent") also doesn't work

Comment: hmm, can you try to add a `System.out.println("test");` to the `doGet()` function and then call `localhost:8080/PrintFormContent` in your browser and check in the log, if you see "test"

Comment: @user3820292 see my update

Comment: I solved it. thanks