# live edit xhtml with wildfly and idea

Tags: intellij-idea, xhtml, wildfly, liveedit

I need to change gui of enterprise application, which contain gui.war and core.war artifacts. After every little change in xhtml or backing bean I build and depoy application by idea run/debug configurations. It takes 1-2 minuts usually. Does Idea has any opportunity to load changes runtime without new long build and deploy.

[image]

Comment: Yes, see [Updating Applications on Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html) Note that in case of xhtml file there could be a caching by the server. To disable it check the `facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD` parameter, which is set in web.xml. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7924117/104891

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when working with .ear, even with the following `web.xml` settings the issue was still persistent:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I had to check "Unpack nested archives" of the .ear in the File->Project Structure:
[image]